# Render mail templete zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

i'm trying to sent an email with a template in Zend framework 2 applicatio.
This is code in my class called "EmailService...".

```
        $view = new PhpRenderer();
    $resolver = new TemplateMapResolver();
    $resolver->setMap(array(
        'mailTemplate' => __DIR__ . '/../../../mail/' . $template['name'] . '.phtml'
    ));
    $view->setResolver($resolver);
    $viewModel = new ViewModel();
    $viewModel->setTemplate('mailTemplate')
            ->setVariables(
                    (!empty($template['variables']) && is_array($template['variables'])) ? $template['variables'] : array()
    );

    $this->_message->addFrom($this->_emailConfig['sender']['address'], $this->_emailConfig['sender']['name'])
            ->addTo($user['email'], $user['login'])
            ->setSubject($subject)
            ->setBody($view->render($viewModel))
            ->setEncoding('UTF-8');
```

Everything work fine but in this templete file I have to create a link to an action (I have specify route for this). But here is a problem. Becouse when I'm trying to use

```
<?php echo $this->url('auth') ; ?>
```

I've got "No RouteStackInterface instance provided" error.

If I use:

```
<?php echo $this->serverUrl(true); ?>
```

everything work fine... Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to create a new instance of the `PhpRenderer`; you can just reuse the already created one.

```
$renderer = $this->serviceManager->get('viewrenderer');

$variables = is_array($template['variables']) ? $template['variables'] : array();
$viewModel = new ViewModel($variables);
$viewModel->setTemplate('mailTemplate');

$html = $renderer->render($viewModel);
```

In order to follow good DI practice, inject the `PhpRenderer` into the email service's `__construct` (rather than the service manager).

Also, the template path can be added in the normal `module.config.php`

```
return array(
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_map' => array(
            'mailTemplate' => __DIR__ . '/../view/foo/bar.phtml',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of modules which make things easy when sending html mails. You can search them [here](http://modules.zendframework.com/?query=mail).

My personal favourite is [MtMail](https://github.com/mtymek/MtMail). You can easily use templates and layouts. You can easily set default headers(From, Reply-To etc.). You can use this [Template Manager](https://github.com/mtymek/MtMail/blob/master/doc/Template%20Manager.md) feature to better organize e-mail templates in object-oriented manner.

### MtMail Usage:

```
$mailService = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('MtMail\Service\Mail');

$headers = array(
    'to' => 'johndoe@domain.com',
    'from' => 'contact@mywebsite.com',
);
$variables = array(
    'userName' => 'John Doe',
);
$message = $mailService->compose($headers, 'application/mail/welcome.phtml', $variables);

$mailService->send($message);
```